# log4j2 with pax-logging: can't use values from StructuredDataMessage

Tags: java, osgi, log4j2, apache-karaf, pax

I'm using pax-logging-api along with pax-logging-log4j2 for logging from my OSGi bundles. I would like to utilize Log4J2's StructuredDataMessage (using EventLogger) to write some messages to a database. However, I'm unable to read the values I put into the StructuredDataMessage from the appenders when using Pax Logging.

The following **works** in a non-OSGi project using the Log4J2 libraries directly:

**log4j2.properties:**

```
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %m%n

appender.event.type = Console
appender.event.name = event
appender.event.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.event.layout.pattern = %marker ${sd:id} ${sd:testKey} %n    %m%n

rootLogger.level = debug
rootLogger.appenderRef.console.ref = STDOUT

logger.event.name = EventLogger
logger.event.level = debug
logger.event.appenderRef.console.ref = event
logger.event.additivity = false
```

**Test.java:**

```
public class Test {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(Test.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StructuredDataMessage msg = new StructuredDataMessage("1", "message", "event");
        msg.put("testKey", "testValue");

        LOGGER.info(msg);
        EventLogger.logEvent(msg);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
 1 testValue event [1 testKey="testValue"] message
EVENT 1 testValue 
    event [1 testKey="testValue"] message
```

Note that the `event` appender properly dereferenced the `sd` keys from the StructuredDataMessage.

However, the following **does not work** in OSGi with pax-logging:

**org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg:**

```
log4j2.appender.console.type = Console
log4j2.appender.console.name = STDOUT
log4j2.appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
log4j2.appender.console.layout.pattern = %m%n

log4j2.appender.event.type = Console
log4j2.appender.event.name = event
log4j2.appender.event.layout.type = PatternLayout
log4j2.appender.event.layout.pattern = %marker \$\\\{sd:id\} \$\\\{sd:testKey\} %n    %m%n

log4j2.rootLogger.level = debug
log4j2.rootLogger.appenderRef.console.ref = STDOUT

log4j2.logger.event.name = EventLogger
log4j2.logger.event.level = debug
log4j2.logger.event.appenderRef.console.ref = event
log4j2.logger.event.additivity = false
```

**Test.java:**

```
public class Test implements BundleActivator {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(Test.class);

    @Override
    public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        StructuredDataMessage msg = new StructuredDataMessage("1", "message", "event");
        msg.put("testKey", "testValue");

        LOGGER.info(msg);
        EventLogger.logEvent(msg, Level.INFO);
    }

    @Override
    public void stop(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
event [1 testKey="testValue"] message
EVENT ${sd:id} ${sd:testKey}
    event [1 testKey="testValue"] message
```

Is there a trick to getting this to work in pax-logging? I am able to access values from the MDC using `\$\\\{ctx:key\}` when applicable, so I'm assuming the syntax is similar. I've also tried using the lookups in patterns for RoutingAppender, FileAppender, etc. to no avail.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** I'm using the latest version of pax-logging-api and pax-logging-log4j2 (1.11.3)

Comment: Please write which pax-logging version are you using and I'll try to reproduce.

Comment: @GrzegorzGrzybek thanks! I'm using version 1.11.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it's not yet a definitive answer - simply comment is too short to describe what happens.

The stack trace with your call is:

```
"pipe-restart 238@10666" prio=5 tid=0xc3 nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
      at org.ops4j.pax.logging.log4j2.internal.PaxLoggerImpl.doLog0(PaxLoggerImpl.java:354)
      at org.ops4j.pax.logging.log4j2.internal.PaxLoggerImpl.doLog(PaxLoggerImpl.java:337)
      at org.ops4j.pax.logging.log4j2.internal.PaxLoggerImpl.inform(PaxLoggerImpl.java:233)
      at org.ops4j.pax.logging.internal.TrackingLogger.inform(TrackingLogger.java:209)
      at org.ops4j.pax.logging.log4jv2.Log4jv2Logger.logMessage(Log4jv2Logger.java:162)
      at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.log(AbstractLogger.java:2102)
      at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.tryLogMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2190)
      at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageTrackRecursion(AbstractLogger.java:2144)
      at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageSafely(AbstractLogger.java:2127)
      at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logIfEnabled(AbstractLogger.java:1828)
      at org.apache.logging.log4j.EventLogger.logEvent(EventLogger.java:56)
      at grgr.test.ActivatorLogging.start(ActivatorLogging.java:39)
...
```

`org.ops4j.pax.logging.log4jv2.Log4jv2Logger.logMessage()` is bridge between *logging facade* and *logging backend*.

Remember - with pax-logging, you can, say, use Commons Logging *facade* with Log4J1 *backend*, or Log4j2 *facade* (and that's what you're doing) with e.g., Logback *backend*.

That's why `org.ops4j.pax.logging.log4jv2.Log4jv2Logger.logMessage()` does this:

```
} else if (level.intLevel() >= Level.INFO.intLevel()) {
    m_delegate.inform(paxMarker, message.getFormattedMessage(), t, fqcn);
```

and your structured message is changed into String `event [1 testKey="testValue"] message`.

Only then configured appenders are called - and the appender with layout that extract structured data can't find it, because the structured message is already converted to plain String.

These 3 lines:

```
  at org.ops4j.pax.logging.log4j2.internal.PaxLoggerImpl.inform(PaxLoggerImpl.java:233)
  at org.ops4j.pax.logging.internal.TrackingLogger.inform(TrackingLogger.java:209)
  at org.ops4j.pax.logging.log4jv2.Log4jv2Logger.logMessage(Log4jv2Logger.java:162)
```

do the *crossing* from pax-logging-api (facade) through `TrackingLogger` (bridge) to pax-logging-log4j2 (backend) losing structured information in between.

I've created https://ops4j1.jira.com/browse/PAXLOGGING-302 and hope to do something about it soon.

EDIT1

The key is that in `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.StructuredDataLookup#lookup()`, this condition is true:

```
if (event == null || !(event.getMessage() instanceof StructuredDataMessage)) {
    return null;
}
```

EDIT2

I've just fixed https://ops4j1.jira.com/browse/PAXLOGGING-302 and this test proves it works:

```
Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("my.logger");

logger.info(new StructuredDataMessage("1", "hello!", "typeX").with("key1", "sd1"));
logger.info(new StringMapMessage().with("key1", "map1"));

List<String> lines = readLines();
assertTrue(lines.contains("my.logger/org.ops4j.pax.logging.it.Log4J2MessagesIntegrationTest typeX/sd1 [INFO] typeX [1 key1=\"sd1\"] hello!"));
assertTrue(lines.contains("my.logger/org.ops4j.pax.logging.it.Log4J2MessagesIntegrationTest ${sd:type}/map1 [INFO] key1=\"map1\""));
```

the configuration is:

```
log4j2.appender.console.type = Console
log4j2.appender.console.name = console
log4j2.appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
log4j2.appender.console.layout.pattern = %c/%C ${sd:type}/${map:key1} [%p] %m%n
log4j2.rootLogger.level = info
log4j2.rootLogger.appenderRef.file.ref = console
```

(you have to use the escape sequences you've used, if configuring via `etc/org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg` in Karaf).